# ShellTile.Create with FlipTileData throws InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I am trying to create a tile using FlipTileData in Windows Phone 8. I use this code:

```
        const string mainPage = "/MainPage.xaml";

        ...

        Uri mp = new Uri(mainPage + "?" + "tileid=" + tileId, UriKind.Relative);
        FlipTileData tileData = new FlipTileData();
        tileData.Title = tileTitle;
        tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + isourl);
        tileData.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + isourl);
        tileData.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + isourl);
        ShellTile.Create(mp, tileData);
```

This throws an InvalidOperationException at the ShellTile.Create method. There are no other tiles with the same Navigation URI. What am I doing wrong here?

This code works fine using the StandardTileData class, excluding the SmallBackgroundImage and WideBackgroundImage properties.

If it matters, the full code is:

```
    const string mainPage = "/MainPage.xaml";

    ...

    private void createbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tileId = new Random().Next().ToString();
        Uri mp = new Uri(mainPage + "?" + "tileid=" + tileId, UriKind.Relative);
        WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(tileGrid, null);

        string isourl = "/Shared/ShellContent/" + tileId + ".jpg";
        IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().CreateFile(isourl);
        wbmp.SaveJpeg(isfs, 173, 173, 0, 100);
        isfs.Close();

        FlipTileData tileData = new FlipTileData();
        tileData.Title = tileTitle;
        tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + isourl);
        tileData.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + isourl);
        tileData.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + isourl);
        ShellTile.Create(mp, tileData);
    }
```

Comment: What does the `mainPage` string contain?

Comment: Edited code to include this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the new tile templates you need to use the overload of `ShellTile.Create()` that includes a third parameter.

This should do the trick:

```
ShellTile.Create(mp, tileData, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Sorry I took so long, I hadn't been working on the project that required this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling this code inside the Closing handler?

> In Windows Phone 8, creating a Tile by using the Create(Uri, ShellTileData) method inside the Closing handler will throw an InvalidOperationException.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx

edit: i guess not, since you said it worked with StandardTileData...

Comment: I'm creating it inside a button clicked handler.